# A question on a Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

(This may sound too simple a question to be asked in MO. But it is a research problem but not an exercise, so I post it here. If it is no appropriate, I will move it to Stackexchange.)

Let $0 < a < b$ be real numbers and $p$ a polynomial. The Fourier transforms of $\exp(-ax^2/2)$ and $\exp(-bx^2/2)$ are (up to constant factors) $\exp(-\xi^2/(2a))$ and $\exp(-\xi^2/(2b))$ respectively. The Fourier transform of $p(x) \exp(-ax^2/2)$ is $q(\xi) \exp(-\xi^2/(2a))$ where $q$ is a polynomial of the same degree as $p$'s.

Suppose we know that a function $f$ has its Fourier transform
$$
\hat{f}(\xi) = \left( q(\xi) e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{2a}} \right) e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{2b}},
$$
then $f$ has a simple expression as the convolution (up to a constant)
$$
f(x) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \left( p(y) e^{-\frac{ay^2}{2}} \right) e^{-\frac{b(x - y)^2}{2}} dy.
$$

My **question** is: if a function $g$ has its Fourier transform
$$
\hat{g}(\xi) =\left( q(\xi) e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{2a}} \right) e^{\frac{\xi^2}{2b}},
$$
is there a simple formula of $g$ in $p$, analogous to the convolution formula above? A naive extrapolation
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \left( p(y) e^{-\frac{ay^2}{2}} \right) e^{\frac{b(x - y)^2}{2}} dy.
$$
does not converge at all.

Comment: I don't understand the notation. You have the variable $x$ for the function and $\xi$ for the Fourier-transform, but what does $\zeta$ mean?

Comment: I did not use the notation $\zeta$. Did I?

Comment: Oh I see, there's a TeX=problem here: when you use $\xi$ in the exponent, the upper loop gets killed and it looks like a $\zeta$.

Comment: When your function is in the Schwartz space, you only need to apply the Fourier transform and multiply the variable by (-1). That's what the inversion formula tells you.

Comment: The well-definedness of $g$ is not a problem, but I need a handy formula. The last integral in my post is a formal solution expected by me, while the divergence is incurable.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $\hat{g}$, as a function of the complex variable $b$, is analytic on some open neighborhood of infinity.